# Ignore shapefile encoding on newest QGIS version

Tags: qgis, encoding

Where can I find the Ignore shapefile encoding checkbox on latest QGIS versions? It used to be on settings > data sources, but it isn't there anymore. It is a very handy option for non-English characters
[image]

Comment: Does the "ENCODING" option in Add vector layer do the same thing or something else?

Comment: use double quotes "" to ignore encoding (via Add vector layer). for shapefiles.

Comment: It was [intentionally removed](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/f36bd8f76cf3153909f9d739b8bc94c1f97605f9).